# Contact Form 7 Custom Validation Doesn't Get Called

Tags: filters, plugin-contact-form-7

I'm trying to change the filter for email so that it reads "Email Address is Required". I check to is if it is empty().

My tag in Contact Form 7 is [email* your-email]

You can see here, I tried everything to change the filter response but nothing works.

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email', 'custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter', 20, 2 );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter', 20, 2 );

function custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    $result->invalidate( $tag, "Email Address is Required" );
    if ( 'your-email' == $tag->name ) {
        $your_email = isset( $_POST['your-email'] ) ? trim( $_POST['your-email'] ) : '';

        if ( empty($your_email) ) {
            $result->invalidate( $tag, "Email Address is Required" );
        } else {
             $result->invalidate( $tag, "Email Address is Required" );
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

What might I be missing?

Thanks

Comment: I noticed, my custom validation works if the field is not marked as required. Not sure why that is, as the filter is exactly how the contact form 7 documentation is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you are already checking if the field is empty with that function, there's no need to use * in the backoffice [email* your-email].

In any case, it's not working because `is_required()`executes first than your function.

**Solutions:**

1) Remove the * in the backend

***OR***

2) **Change the priority**

```
// From 20 to 5 should work
// You only need to apply this to this filter as it is the one for required fields

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email*', 'custom_email_confirmation_validation_filter', 5, 2 );
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How did you know that 5 would work for priority?

Comment: @BestDevTutorials actually I can't be 100% sure it will work for everyone, but I know that:

1 - when you an * to a field in a Contact Form 7 shortecode, it will trigger a function  | 

 2 - that function has a lower priority then 5 | 

 3 - Unless you have another filter with higher priority than 5 it should work just fine